# SAP HANA Calculate percentage in a script calculation view

Tags: hana

I was wondering if there was a way to achieve this kind of aggregation :

[image: Hana graphical calculation view with calculated column]

In practice: using (I think) CE_AGGREGATION how is possible to create a percentage formula like the one in "calculated column"?
I try a lot of combination (CE_PROJECTION,CE_AGGREGATION, CE_CALC...) but no ones of them works.

This because it seems that the script do a kind of sum(A/b*100), but I would like to obtain sum(a)/sum(b)*100. In graphical mode is instead very simple!

Someone has an idea about how to reproduce that?

Answer (score 0):

Really, don't bother using the CE_-functions anymore.
Use SQL instead.

This is not only much easier but also SAP HANA has more options to rewrite and optimize the statements internally. 
This should then lead to more options for better performance.

Anyhow, to do calculations like that, there is the CE_CALC function, that you can use within a CE_PROJECTION function.

Again: stop using CE_-functions. SQL is King!

Comment: Hi, 
thank you for your answer.... so, I'am the first that prefer SQL (standard) to Ce functions.

But the problem is born first in SQL on HANA environment. A very SIMPLE Sql to test it:

1) Look at this simple query:
select "DocEntry","CardCode","DocTotal","GrosProfit",("DocTotal"/"GrosProfit")*100 as "PRC" from OINV

2) Put it on a calculation view on HANA

Comment: 3) If you test the result in HANA Studio in Analyses, you can see that if you put in label axis DocEntry and Cardcode the percentage calculation is correct. But if you try to group it by CardCode, HANA studio show a wrong result

This happens because it SUM the percentage (instead of calculate percentage of SUM).

In graphical environment (always calculation view) this is possible defining a Calculated Column.

But... how to do the same thing in a pure script environment???

Comment: I see what you mean. The problem here is that this very feature to apply the calculated column formula AFTER the *final* aggregation is only available for graphical calc views The reason for that is that for those types of views, HANA does not behave like a rational query processor, but instead rearranges the execution based on the final SQL query that consumes the calculation view.